# What do I do to get past that cmd coming up while installing windows?

Tags: windows, setup, cmd.exe

Eveytime I try to install windows, it always ends up with a command prompt and not continuing on the setup. How do I deal with it without logging on the previous windows I have? Is there a command I can type to make the setup continue? Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 0):

The Command Prompt window is appearing because the installation is starting and working. It does these features automatically though. Your installation is probably corrupted and you should get some new installation media. Either by ordering new installation CD's or getting a download .iso from Microsoft's Website.